# How consume ajax file upload aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my Webform.aspx file have following js

```
$('#Result').click(function () {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file');
  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('myfile', file );
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm2.aspx/HelloWorld",
    data: { ss: formData },
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(msg) {
      // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
      $("#Result").text(msg.d);
    }
  });
});`
```

This is my Webform.aspx.cs code. And i hope to write code for save file inside this method and return json respond.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
    public static string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello: " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
    }
```

The problem is Helloword method does not execute for my ajax call.

Comment: Check browser console for javascript error